# How to write this complex query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

hello every one please how i can write  this query :

```
$laureats=Laureat::select('laureats.*')
    ->from(DB::raw(" SELECT laureats.nom FROM laureats,traces WHERE laureats.id=traces.laureat_id AND traces.etat_id=$etat
            and traces.etat_id=(select etat_id from traces where traces.laureat_id=laureats.id ORDER BY traces.dateTrace desc limit 1)"))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Please try explaining what this code is trying to do :)

Comment: Yes, i want to search the Laureat(Model) that his last $etat is the some that i pass in parametre. here i have two tables laureats and traces and key primary of the firt (laureats) is  foreign key in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you just asked, is in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries):

I see you're running a SELECT query with a WHERE clause with an AND, and another query in a where clause.

Im gonna explain it to you:

Select query with just laureats.nom as result would be like this:

```
$nom = DB::table('laureats')->pluck('nom');
```

Using multiple where's:

```
$nom = DB::table('laureats')->where('votes', '>', 100)->where('votes', '>', 100)->pluck('nom');
```

You can run a query in another query like so:

```
->where(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                  ->from('traces')
                  ->whereRaw('something = something');
        })
```

This is what it would somewhat look like. Since this is all in the docs, you should play around with it yourself.

Comment: this is the some query in SQL :   SELECT laureats.* FROM laureats,traces WHERE laureats.id=traces.laureat_id AND traces.etat_id=3 and traces.etat_id=(select etat_id from traces where traces.laureat_id=laureats.id ORDER BY traces.dateTrace desc limit 1)

Comment: here this is a parameter that change evry make of searching.